# ssh from windows at my house to school linux server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

this is my first post here so any other information you need I can provide.

I am trying to ssh into my school server and I tried from command line, I tried putty, and I tried xtogo. xtogo and command line I tried from windows 10 and an ubuntu virtual machine.

from windows

```
ssh -vvv myusername@myschool.edu
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/copyp/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "myschool.edu" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myschool.edu [12.12.12.12] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000022866901A50
debug1: connect to address 12.12.12.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host myschool.edu port 22: Connection timed out
```

I CAN ssh from my phone on a mobile network but not from wifi.

the school server is Linux mint, just incase I have to do anything special for that. I forwarded the ports and made rules for the firewall and I can ssh into https://sdf.org/ when I created an account and tested ssh from my wifi. Can anyone tell me what might be the problem. any additional information can be provided.

**EDIT** : I can ping the server

Comment: The error is an indication that the outgoing port is blocked and unable to communicate with the server. The fact you can ping the server (12.12.12.12) is only an indication you can communicate with the server on another port[,](https://superuser.com/questions/1478901/how-to-overcome-blocked-ssh-attempt/1478908#1478908)

Comment: but I can ssh to https://sdf.org/ from windows on my wifi

Comment: Are you positive the SSH port on the 12.12.12.12 actually is port 22?  The error you received indicates your unable to make any communication on that port (the connection was refused).  That is typically due to the fact the outgoing port is blocked on the client-side or it's blocked on the server-side.    Have you contacted the administrator for 12.12.12.12 for assistance?  There is another possibility, you are using an extremely old copy of LibreSSL, it's possible the version you are using does not support the same ciphers the server supports.

Comment: What exactly is "My W-Fi"?

Comment: my wifi means from my house, I can connect to sdf.org with putty, but not my school. I am talking with the administrators to get some help. do you think maybe that the server has me blocked? I could access the service last school year but this year I can not. if maybe I am blocked I could ask the admin to see and unblock me

Comment: its was fixed, the administrator of the server said that i was blacklisted, it works perfectly now